# Why can't I iterate over a list of Firebase Img URLS, but can access each on individually?

Tags: firebase, loops, ember.js

I have an array of Firebase storage URLs that link to images like so:

```
[
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xyz-app-1540127382149.appspot.com/o/images%2F-LR855-bwb_IuYAFeYlf%2Fyyz-1.jpg?alt=media&token=e39d4dd0-6821-477a-b165-4ead2eb0a8c4",
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xyz-app-1540127382149.appspot.com/o/images%2F-LR855-bwb_IuYAFeYlf%2abc-1.jpg?
]
```

**Paste these into a browser? Works.**
**Get single item in array and add it to an img element src? Works.**

**Iterate over the array and try to add each to an img element src? Stack Error.**

```
{{#each images as |img|}}
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img
      class="d-block w-100"
      src={{img}}
      alt="Post Image"
    >
   </div>
 {{/each}}

stack: "Error: Assertion Failed: fullName must be a proper full name
```

I don't get it. Why can I get a single link in the array and it will display, yet when I iterate over the list I get an error..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is a result of angle bracket components. The solution would be to use anything other than `img` here for the loop variable: `{{#each images as |img|}}`. `<img` is invoking the block argument (`|img|`) as a component inside the each.

So try instead

`{{#each images as |image|}}
...
{{/each}}`

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you!